# Can't view tables of my local database (.mdf file )

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, database-connection

I created a project in visual studio 2013. I'm using code first to create a local database and  then insert data in it. I can print the content in the program it is working and everything is perfect but when I try to navigate the database with the server explorer the tables that i created doesn't exist.

[image: If you look at tables i can't expand]

I tried opening the mdf file with SQL Server (attaching it) but there also can't find any content and it shows that the database doesn't contain any tables.

How can I see what my database contains?
Thanks

Comment: What query are you using? What connection string are you using? What method to get the data are you using? Why did you attached the screenshot it does not explain anything? One more thing what is the name of your table and database that you created manually?

Comment: i updated the post for connection string , now i just want to see the content of my database.

Comment: I still can not see the connection string or the query you are using to get the data or the names of your database & table. I can not help you without the details

Comment: sorry if my english is bad, this is my problem:
after creating the database and adding content into it i can't view the table that i've created in the server explorer (look at the image)

Comment: Yes to diagnose what the actual problem is I want to know what is the name of your database and table that you created?

Comment: i think the name is generated automatically by code first,
it will be : ConsoleApplication3.blogContext

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54364/discussion-between-syed-farjad-zia-zaidi-and-user3290726).